# How to draw heatmap based on density map

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, distribution

Im trying to draw a heatmap from a given distribution. Ex, a normal distribution of a 2D array will look like this:
[image: 2D array]

[image: density graph]

If i have another density graph like this:
[image: sample]

How can i draw a heatmap that look like the 1st one. This is the code i used to draw the 1st heat map:

```
  output_width = 40
  output_height = 40
  p_x = 20
  p_y = 20
  sigma = 1
  X1 = np.linspace(0, output_width, output_width)
  Y1 = np.linspace(0, output_height, output_height)
  [X, Y] = np.meshgrid(X1, Y1)
  X = X - floor(p_x)
  Y = Y - floor(p_y)
  D2 = X * X + Y * Y
  E2 = 2.0 * sigma ** 2
  Exponent = D2 / E2
  heatmap = np.exp(-Exponent)
  heatmap = (heatmap - heatmap.min()) / (heatmap.max() - heatmap.min())
  plt.imshow(heatmap)
```

Comment: Your density graphs are radial densities? Otherwise you need to specify a density in 2 directions

Answer (score 0):

```
output_width = 40
output_height = 40
mu = 0; sigma=0.1
x, y = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(-1, 1, 40),
                   np.linspace(-1, 1, 40))
dst = np.sqrt(x**2+y**2)

# lower normal part of gaussian
normal = 1/(2.0 * np.pi * sigma**2)

# Calculating Gaussian filter
gauss = np.exp(-((dst-mu)**2 / (2.0 * sigma**2))) * normal
plt.imshow(gauss)
```

Gives:
[image]